# Can i use Content-type: application/force-download for file download?

Tags: java, javascript, php

Here is my code and it's working fine, Is this the right way to do this???

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.extn");
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private");
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use like the following:

```
<?php
$file = 'filename.doc'; //your file name with proper path here.

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Source URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Thanks & Regards,

**Vivek**